# How can i make the checkbox value a string and store in db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If you defined a given field as `boolean`, then it will be stored as `boolean` , if you define the attribute as `integer`, then it will have the value 1 or 0, and if it's a `String`, you will have "1" or "0". But i want to store a `text` when the checkbox is `checked` and `empty` when not checked. Is this is possible?

Comment: So the text column should contain "checked" or "empty"? Or by empty do you mean `nil`? Any particular reason you need to break conventions like this? Anyway, you could use a callback in the model (say, `before_validation`) to set the attribute to "checked" or nil (or "empty").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your create/update action, add an extra check to see the value of as posted by your form. Based on that value you can set it to whatever string you want,

.i.e if check.checked? check = "string A" or "string B"